# Angular 7 Material: Horizontally align cards

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

If I have more (material-)cards, they are getting aligned vertically. 
How is it possible, to align the cards horizontally from left to right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the attribute **`fxLayout="row"`**

```
<div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutGap="12px"  [style.margin-top]="'12px'">
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-card-horizontal?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**